# How can I define a custom Primary Color like we get from SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want define a Color like SwiftUI Primary Color! Right now I am solving my issue with using `colorScheme` and also using an `if` like in the code:

---

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        CustomPrimaryView()
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            .cornerRadius(10)
        Color.primary
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            .cornerRadius(10)
    }
}
```

---

```
struct CustomPrimaryView: View {   
    @Environment(\.colorScheme)
    var colorScheme
    var body: some View {
        colorScheme == .light ?
            Color(red: 0.1, green: 0.1, blue: 0.1) :
            Color(red: 0.95, green: 0.95, blue: 0.95)
    }
}
```

---

I would like define a customPrimary Color and access it as Color not as View which dynamically do the job that I am doing in that view. How can we do this in SwiftUI?

---

### . . . also still looking for pure SwiftUI Answer ! ! !

---

Comment: If by that you mean a `Color` that is environment-dependent, then the recommended method is by defining it at your `xcasset`s file and then using it with `Color("myCustomColor")`

Comment: Do you mean you want something like the `UIColor(dynamicProvider:)`initialiser, but for `Color`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're talking about is a *dynamic* color, which chooses its RGB values at the moment it is applied to fill pixels, based on the current appearance traits.

SwiftUI `Color` does not (as of 2021) have direct support for creating custom dynamic colors in code. Here are two ways of creating a dynamic `Color`.

## Asset Catalog

You can create a dynamic color by creating a Color Set in an asset catalog. It looks like this:

[image: color set in asset catalog in Xcode]

Read more about it in [Xcode help: Create asset catalogs and sets](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/11.4/index.html?localePath=en.lproj#/dev10510b1f7).

You can then load the color set as a SwiftUI `Color` using the [`Color.init(_ name: String, bundle: Bundle = nil)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/color/init(_:bundle:)) initializer. For example:

```
let myColor = Color("MyColor")
```

## `UIColor`

You can use [`UIColor.init(dynamicProvider:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/3238041-init) to create a dynamic `UIColor`, then wrap it in a SwiftUI `Color`:

```
let uiColor = UIColor { traits in
    if traits.userInterfaceStyle == .dark {
        return .init(red: 0.567, green: 0.622, blue: 0.725, alpha: 1)
    } else {
        return .init(red: 0.204, green: 0.324, blue: 0.374, alpha: 1)
    }
}

let color = Color(uiColor: uiColor)
```

If you're targeting macOS, you can use [`NSColor.init(name:dynamicProvider:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscolor/3294481-init).

Comment: Thanks, It solves my issue, and it works! Just a side question, `colorScheme` Environment get updated in body of `App` for us in SwiftUI and get ready for us to use in `ContentView`, but which method Apple use to understand the mode changes? I now we are not Apple but trying to guess could help me also. Because the part of `???` must be feed with a method! `.environment(\.colorScheme, ???)` Do you think that Apple would use `userInterfaceStyle` for that job?

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you wanted something like this

```
extension Color {
    static var customPrimaryColor: Color {
        let currentStyle = UIScreen.main.traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle
        return currentStyle == .light ? Color(red: 0.1, green: 0.1, blue: 0.1) : Color(red: 0.95, green: 0.95, blue: 0.95)
    }
}
```

and you can use it directly like

```
var body: some View {
    Text("HELLO WORLD!")
        .foregroundColor(.customPrimaryColor)
}
```

and this will be updated automatically on device's color scheme changes

Tested with Xcode 13 / iOS 15

Comment: I just tried your code with xCode Version 12.5.1 (12E507), but it did not update the color! Maybe the issue is because of xCode version!